# search within text files and display containing folder in listbox with visual basic

Tags: vb.net, search, text, basic

I am new to programming to please forgive me if this is an easy one...

The directory needing to be searched is stored called "archiveDir" and the text I'm searching for is stored in "faultSearch" (textbox).

Where I am having difficulty, is within "archiveDir" there are many folders named as serial numbers. If the code finds any reference to the inputted string in any .txt contained within any serial number folder, I want the serial number to be displayed in a listbox (lets call it "ListBox1" for now). It is likely that the searched string will be found more than once if it is found at all so I also need to ensure it only adds each serial number once...

I realise that I haven't provided any code to start off with, but I'm struggling to get started!

Comment: To clarify, if the directory where the string was found is:
C:\Documents\Archive\123456\TextFile.txt
Then I would like:
123456
Displayed in the listbox

Comment: If you *really* want to clarify. show us the code so we dont have to guess what it looks like, what approach you took and what your level of expertise is.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour]

Comment: The difficulty I am having is I don't have much idea where to start... I don't want someone to do it for me I just want some ideas for a place to start

Comment: Gobs and gobs of posts here on getting files and filtering by file or folder.  Get your Google-Fu on to get an idea where to start, then you can post a proper question when you get stuck.  SO is not for ideas. suggestions, general direction or tutorials.  Please read [ask] and take the [Tour].